# How to work apktool build with library project?

Tags: android, library-project

I can use apktool to decode apk then build again for my normal android project.

But when I tried same thing with the project that depends on the library project (appcompat), it failed with following errors.

Do I need to build with library project and if so, how can I specify that?

```
$ apktool build apkdecode repack.apk
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Smaling...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building resources...
/<currentdir>/apkdecode/res/values/styles.xml:59: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
/<currentdir>/apkdecode/res/values/styles.xml:99: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
/<currentdir>/apkdecode/res/values/styles.xml:146: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
/<currentdir>/apkdecode/res/values/styles.xml:176: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
/<currentdir>/apkdecode/res/values/styles.xml:192: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base.DropDownItem'.
/<currentdir>/apkdecode/res/values/styles.xml:218: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
/<currentdir>/apkdecode/res/values/styles.xml:225: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base'.
/<currentdir>/apkdecode/res/values/styles.xml:242: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Base'.
/<currentdir>/apkdecode/res/values/styles.xml:275: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
/<currentdir>/apkdecode/res/values-v14/styles.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
/<currentdir>/apkdecode/res/values/styles.xml:467: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Base'.
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [aapt, p, --min-sdk-version, 8, --target-sdk-version, 11, -F, /var/folders/6l/q11hqqj57rs0lgxcx1njdlxc0000gn/T/APKTOOL2534308390228031373.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, /<toolpath>/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /<currentdir>/apkdecode/res, -M, /<currentdir>/apkdecode/AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:358)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResources(Androlib.java:283)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:206)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:176)
    at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:228)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:79)
Caused by: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [aapt, p, --min-sdk-version, 8, --target-sdk-version, 11, -F, /var/folders/6l/q11hqqj57rs0lgxcx1njdlxc0000gn/T/APKTOOL2534308390228031373.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, /<toolpath>/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /<currentdir>/apkdecode/res, -M, /<currentdir>/apkdecode/AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:357)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:336)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [aapt, p, --min-sdk-version, 8, --target-sdk-version, 11, -F, /var/folders/6l/q11hqqj57rs0lgxcx1njdlxc0000gn/T/APKTOOL2534308390228031373.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, /<toolpath>/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /<currentdir>/apkdecode/res, -M, /<currentdir>/apkdecode/AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.util.OS.exec(OS.java:89)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:355)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem of apktool v1 (1.5.3).
There are several ways to solve it.

**1. Edit styles.xml.**
Add the empty 'parent' attribute to the tags on the error lines. For example:

Before

```
59: <style name="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionBar">
```

After

```
59: <style name="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionBar" parent="">
```

Then build the project. In this way you need to edit xml every time you decode apk.

**2. Edit apktool sources and rebuild it.**
You have to edit method 'serializeToResValuesXml' in the file 'android-apktool/brut.apktool/apktool-lib/src/main/java/brut/androlib/res/data/value/ResStyleValue.java':

Before

```
if (!mParent.isNull()) {
    serializer.attribute(null, "parent", mParent.encodeAsResXmlAttr());
}
```

After

```
if (!mParent.isNull()) {
    serializer.attribute(null, "parent", mParent.encodeAsResXmlAttr());
} else if (res.getResSpec().getName().indexOf('.') != -1) {
    serializer.attribute(null, "parent", "");
}
```

**3. Just use apktool v2 :)**